# Nix: Write Google ZX script that is invokable without the mjs extension

Tags: nix, google-zx

I want to write Google ZX scripts in an idiomatic way in Nix, but how can I do that? `nixpkgs` only offers `writeShellScriptBin` which is tied to bash as interpreter. How can I change the interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

To solve it idiomatically, you could create a `writeZxScriptBin` attribute similar to [`writeShellScriptBin`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix). Luckily, `zx` is already packaged in `<nixpkgs>`. Hence, we can write a `zx-script-writer-bin.nix` like this:

```hs
# This returns a writer that creates an executable Google ZX script in `<pkg>/bin/%name`
# with the provided content. Similar to `writeShellScriptBin`, it consumes the name of
# the script and the NodeJS/ZX-script content as parameters.

{ pkgs }:

name: text:

let
  mjsBin = pkgs.writeTextFile {
    name = "${name}-mjs";
    executable = true;
    # For Google ZX, the .mjs extension is mandatory.
    destination = "/bin/${name}.mjs";
    text = ''
      #!${pkgs.zx}/bin/zx
      ${text}
    '';
  };
in
# Shebang script enables to call the zx-script without the .mjs version.
pkgs.writeTextFile {
  name = "${name}";
  executable = true;
  destination = "/bin/${name}";
  text = ''
    #!${mjsBin}/bin/${name}.mjs
  '';
}
```

We can invoke it like this:

```bash
$ nix-build -E "
    let
      pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
      writeZxScriptBin = pkgs.callPackage ./write-zx-script-bin.nix {}; 
    in
    writeZxScriptBin \"foo\" ''
      const a = 7                            
      console.log(\`hello! sum=''\${3 + a}\`)
    ''" && result/bin/foo
```

Note that there is some escaping required. Alternatively, you can work with `builtins.readFile` to write the script code in pure JavaScript